# Windows Phone 8.1 non Silverlight VB - not changing colour of rectangle

Tags: vb.net, colors, windows-phone-8.1, rectangles

I am trying to get my rectangle to change colour after the user has pressed 4 buttons. However it wont. here are the codes.

```
Private Sub button5_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button5.Click

    If currentplayer.Text = "X" Then
        button5.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green)
        currentplayer.Text = "O"

    Else
        If currentplayer.Text = "O" Then
            button5.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue)
            currentplayer.Text = "X"
       End If
    End If
    Win()
End Sub


Private Sub Win()

    Dim Green As New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green)

    If button2.Background Is Green And button5.Background Is Green And button8.Background Is Green And button4.Background Is Green Then
        square1Green.Fill = New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green)
    End If
End Sub
```

I have only included one of the buttons as they are all the same, just the button numbers are different.

UPDATE**

```
  Private Sub Win()

    ''SQUARE ONE
    Dim button2Background = TryCast(button2.Background, SolidColorBrush)
    Dim button5Background = TryCast(button5.Background, SolidColorBrush)
    Dim button8Background = TryCast(button8.Background, SolidColorBrush)
    Dim button4Background = TryCast(button4.Background, SolidColorBrush)

    If button2Background IsNot Nothing AndAlso button2Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Green And button5Background IsNot Nothing AndAlso button5Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Green And button8Background IsNot Nothing AndAlso button8Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Green And button4Background IsNot Nothing AndAlso button4Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Green Then
        square1Green.Fill = New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green)

    End If
End Sub
```

UPDATE 2.
Sorry for the questions, how can i make an else if statement using this?
what i am aimming for is if there are 4 buttons coloured and the currentplayer.text = "X" then the square will be Green, however if the buttons all have colours in them and the currentplayer.text = "O" then the square will fill to the colour Blue.

Thanks again for your help :)

```
Private Sub Win()

    ''SQUARE ONE
    Dim button2Background = TryCast(button2.Background, SolidColorBrush)
    Dim button5Background = TryCast(button5.Background, SolidColorBrush)
    Dim button8Background = TryCast(button8.Background, SolidColorBrush)
    Dim button4Background = TryCast(button4.Background, SolidColorBrush)

    If currentplayer.Text = "O" And button2Background IsNot Nothing AndAlso button2Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Green Or button2Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Blue And button5Background IsNot Nothing AndAlso button5Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Green Or button5Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Blue And button8Background IsNot Nothing AndAlso button8Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Green Or button8Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Blue And button4Background IsNot Nothing AndAlso button4Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Green Or button4Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Blue Then
        square1Green.Fill = New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green)

    Else
        If currentplayer.Text = "X" And button2Background IsNot Nothing AndAlso button2Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Green Or button2Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Blue And button5Background IsNot Nothing AndAlso button5Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Green Or button5Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Blue And button8Background IsNot Nothing AndAlso button8Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Green Or button8Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Blue And button4Background IsNot Nothing AndAlso button4Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Green Or button4Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Blue Then
            square1Green.Fill = New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue)

        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're doing `TryCast` on `button2` four times, you should be doing it on 2, 5, 8, and 4.

Comment: @PaulAbbott OMG you are 100% right, i have been trying everything i cant believe i let that one slip past me, i must not be drinking enough coffee with these late nights.

At this stage it looks like it is working, you are a every clever man!

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @PaulAbbott - Just a quick updating, if you could people lead me in the right direction, that would be marvelous :)

Comment: You already marked an answer. You shouldn't try posting multiple questions in a single question. Your `Else` statement. Move the `If` below it on to the same line so it's `Else If currentpl.....` then you only need a single `End If`

Comment: sorry about that, i thought there just a multiple answers as there is always more than one way of doing something, i'll be sure to read the website's rules once more.

On the other hand after i tried your suggestion, i still cant make it work, thanks for the heads up once again with the post.

Comment: No I mean it would be hard for someone to add a new answer that only addresses 1 part of your problem because the other answer covered it. :) There is more than one way of doing something but when you're asking how to do 3 somethings, it's harder to get a good answer that can also help others in the future.

Comment: ohhhh i see now, well yeah, that makes sense, thanks again mate :)

Comment: No problem. And what you said about how a lot of people use C#, I mostly use it too, but I love the BASIC language so I try and watch for any vb questions :)

Comment: i wanna learn C# as everyone online is saying that Microsoft are cutting Vb.net in the near future. I just haven't found the time to really sit down and try and get into C#, might leave it for a rainy day ahahaha.

Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

`Is` is a reference operator; it checks that two references are ultimately referring to the same object.  Since `Green` is declared `new`, `button2.Background Is Green` will never be true because `button2.Background` is a reference to a *different* `SolidColorBrush`.  The fact they both happen to be green is meaningless to the `Is` operator.

> The Is operator determines if two object references refer to the same
>   object. **However, it does not perform value comparisons**. If object1 and
>   object2 both refer to the exact same object instance, result is True;
>   if they do not, result is False.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx

You probably need to do something like (sorry, haven't done VB in a while)

```
Dim button2Background = TryCast(button2.Background, SolidColorBrush)
If button2Background isNot Nothing AndAlso button2Background.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Green...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you are definitely leading me in the right place. Just one small problem, if i click the button2 and none of the other buttons listed have the background colour of green, the rectangle will still change to the colour green.

I had it doing the same before using the "If not button2.background" statement, i have posted an update to the code above, do you have any ideas?

Also thanks for the link, i will be sure to take a look at it, yeah most people use C#, so its pretty hard to find support, but with that being said a huge thanks to you for helping :)